# How to import GPU tensorflow in Spyder IDE (without anaconda)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

I've recently installed tensorflow with GPU support on my Ubuntu 16.04 successfully and I was able to successfully run some tests in Terminal. Later I decided it would be easier to have an IDE for writing python code, and I'd just import numpy and tensorflow into IDE and run everything there. Having installed Tensorflow successfully I didn't want to create another Anaconda version of everything so I just installed Spyder2 directly from Ubuntu software. However, when I try importing tensorflow in Spyder2

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

it failed with following message:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python      
/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python    
/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python 
/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)

ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python    
interpreter from there.
```

I could import numpy no problem but not tensorflow. I'm new to Linux; what is it that I'm missing here? Or do I need anaconda in order to use Spyder and Tensorflow? Thanks!

Comment: Your cuda is not installed or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set correctly.

Comment: I'm sure CUDA has been installed since I can run tensorflow in command line. I understand that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is an environment variable – are you saying the environment variable is not set properly for Spyder to look for Tensorflow? If not, how should I tell Spyder where to look for Tensorflow?

Comment: I think you need to start Spyder from a terminal so that it grab your environment variables (in this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) correctly.

Comment: I have the same question as you. I installed tensorflow GPU on Ubuntu16.04, and it runs normally. But if I use PyCharm IDE, it tells me ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

These environment variables must be set to let TensorFlow know where to find Cuda:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
```